# Sticky Cookies in Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've set a cookie in Scala similar to the following:

```
val cookies:Seq[Cookie] = new Seq()
val nDaysExpire:Int = 2000
val nSecondsExpire:Int = nDaysExpire * 24 * 60 * 60
val cookie:Cookie = new Cookie(sCookieID, sValue, Option(nSecondsExpire))
cookies = cookies:+ cookie
Ok(views.html.main(sID)).withCookies(cookies:_*)
```

and then I immediately delete the cookie in JavaScript. I have even deleted the cookie 30 seconds after the page has loaded.

When I reload the page, the Scala code still sees the cookie. But in the JavaScript, the cookie is no where to be found when I call: document.cookie.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie), the constructor for `Cookie` takes a boolean parameter named `httpCookie`. The default value is `true`.

HttpOnly cookies cannot be seen by javascript. So, if you want to delete your cookie from javascript, try setting this to false.

```
val cookie:Cookie = new Cookie(sCookieID, sValue, Option(nSecondsExpire), httpOnly = false)
```

By Jeff Atwoord in [Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/)

> When you tag a cookie with the HttpOnly flag, it tells the browser that this particular cookie should only be accessed by the server. Any attempt to access the cookie from client script is strictly forbidden.

Comment: THANKS! I had to modify your suggestion a little bit as the Cookie class's constructor required 3 additional params before passing false as the httpOnly param. I used the default values for those 3 additional params: new Cookie(sCookieID, sValue, Option(nSecondsExpire), "/", scala.None, false, false)

Comment: p.s. Although, I can now see the cookie in JavaScript, I cannot seem to delete the cookie in JavaScript. I will post that as another question as the original question was answered.