# JavaScript can't delete/modify cookie created using Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've created a cookie in Scala, which I would like Javascript to be able to delete and/or modify.

Here is how I created the cookie in Scala ensuring the httpOnly param is set to false: (
[Sticky Cookies in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581269/sticky-cookies-in-scala)
)

I used the following method to delete the cookie in JavaScript, but the cookie does not delete.
( [javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie) )

Aside from attempting to delete the cookie, it doesn't seem like I can modify the contents of the cookie either.

How can I ensure the JavaScript can modify and delete the cookie created in Scala?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the cookie on the client viewing your web site?  That would have nothing to do with scala - it's all in browser, on the client's computer.

Comment: I am attempting to delete and/or modify the cookie in the browser using JavaScript. Immediately after I make a change or delete it, I use JavaScript to see the change. However, no change is observed. Do I have to set the cookie in a special way in Scala to allow the client/JavaScript to make changes to the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. 
I had to ensure that both the cookie created in Scala and the one deleted/modified in JavaScript both had the same path.

For example, in Scala:

```
new Cookie(sCookieID, sValue, Option(nSecondsExpire), "/", scala.None, false, false)
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = sCookieID + "=" + sValue+ "; " + sExpire + "; path=/";
```

Notice the path in both examples used "/". Once I used the same path, I was able to delete/modify the cookies in JavaScript. Before this I hadn't explicitly set the path in the JavaScript code.